# Highlight dates on react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-datepicker

I have an array of dates in "MM/DD/YYYY" format. But passing this array via the `hightlightDates` prop to `react-datepicker` is not highlighting the days on the calendar. How can I accomplish this?

```
<DatePicker
  showIcon
  selected={startDate}
  customInput={<CustomInput />}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  minDate={new Date()}
  highlightDates={[datesWithEvent]}
  wrapperClassName="calendar-wrapper"
  calendarClassName="calendar"
  className="datepicker"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DatePicker` expects an array of dates. You are passing an array or arrays of dates. Remove the '[', ']' should work.

```
  highlightDates={datesWithEvent}
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be read inside the documentation [here](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-highlight-dates) you need to pass an array of `Date` objects rather than strings to the `highlightDates` prop. The example is using the `subDays` method from [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

```
export default function MyDatePicker(): JSX.Element {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      highlightDates={[subDays(new Date(), 7), addDays(new Date(), 7)]}
      placeholderText="This highlights a week ago and a week from today"
    />
  );
};
```

Please note that you should do some research on your own before posting to StackOverflow. A look at the library documentation would've probably sufficed.